# How to link my angular2 template to the node js express backend

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I try to connect backend (NodeJS, Express) with Frontend (Angular 2) but I have no idea how to start. Can any one help me how can I link the backend with the frontend, if there is a configuration to do or code that I have to implement.

Comment: Check the docs: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2/26878/getting-started-with-angular-2-with-node-js-expressjs-backend-http-example-incl#t=201704091430256514428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angular CLI Project.
Do
ng build --prod --base-href . to generate the dist folder.

Now serve this folder via node JS
Below is snippet which will serve the dist fodler.

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`))
```

Comment: thanks for u'r help! I have a question can I use restful web service to connect the backend and the frontend!

Comment: Ofcourse..all the services can be used in angular2.!!! You can accept as answer and upvote it if it helped...